# ComboBox loses state when clicked away

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` with an `ItemsSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>`.  This ComboBox is part of a detail view which updates dynamically based on a selected master item.

The issue I'm having is that the `ComboBox` `SelectedItem`  does not persist after the master item is changed.  If I click away and then back to the item the selection in the ComboBox is cleared.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show us some code? In particular how you're binding the `SelectedItem`, and what data object it's being bound to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are better ways to do this but this approach seemed to work:

The `ObservableCollection<T>` had to be a property in the the source object I am binding to.  Previously I was using a `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=VisualParent}` expression that was getting the source property from a parent in the visual tree.

If anyone has insight into why this was the case feel free to leave comment on this for my own (and others) learning.